# How many samples to be reasonably sure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, sampling-theory

I am new to probability, and I am struggling with the right language to ask or google this question.

I have a population of size $n$ and everyone is say some color. I want to verify that at least half the population is red to within some $\epsilon$ accuracy. How many members of the population do I need to query?

I am not sure which of the main theorems of probability to use - chernoff bound, Markov, central limit theorem, etc.

Comment: This is really a statistics question, and like all statistical questions, has a twinge of philosophy packed into it.  A Bayesian answer will not look like a frequentist answer, and so on, being based on different understandings of what "within some $\epsilon$ accuracy" means.  Maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this question.